# Conditionals decoration of functions in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

For debugging purpose I want to write a function to do this:

1. If debug_mode == 0 doesn't echo any message.
2. If debug_mode == 1 echoes the message to the stdout with print()
3. If debug_mode == 2 echoes the message to a log file

I've thinked do that with function decorators (that I've never used before).

Actually, I want to substitute some `print()` that I've put in some points to show me intermediate values and while learn about function decorators.

I don't want to create a class to do that.  This is my approach, but it doesn't work:

```
import logging

FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s %(funcName)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT, datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

def debug(func):
    def _debug(deb=0, *args, **kwargs):
        if deb == 1:
            print(msg)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        if deb == 2:
            logging.debug(msg)
    return _debug

@debug
def echo(msg, deb=0):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    debug_mode = 1
    echo("This is a debugging message!", debug_mode)
```

It will be better if I haven't to pass the param debug_mode and in the decorator function I can use the debug state directly from the `__main__`.

Comment: Why not making the debug settings global?

Comment: @bereal That is my planned solution if I don't find any other.  I ever try to avoid the use of globals.

Comment: Same here, but if there is a place for globals in the world, then it's debugging & logging. You can also rely on an environment variable, then `debug` may even return the original function if debugging is unneeded.

Comment: Why not use logging module? Printing debugging information is troublesome, any trivial thing like 'when to flush' may affect time difference between print() call and effect appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is the way you pass arguments. When you do `echo("This is a debugging message!", debug_mode)` you are in fact invoking `def _debug(deb=0, *args, **kwargs)` and all the arguments are messed up (`deb` becomes `"This is a debugging message!"` etc). On StackOverflow there is an amazing [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python) on how to use decorators.

I'm not sure why do you need `*args, **kwargs` in you code. I personally believe that there is no need for any decoration in your particular case. Anyway, for educational purposes the working code with decorators may loo like:

```
import logging

FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s %(funcName)s'
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', level=logging.DEBUG, format=FORMAT, datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

def debug(func):
    def _debug(msg, deb=0):
        if deb == 1:
            func(msg, deb)
        if deb == 2:
            print 'Log: ' + msg + ' Level: ' + str(deb)
            logging.debug(msg)
    return _debug

@debug
def echo(msg, deb):
    print 'Echo: ' + msg + ' Level: ' + str(deb) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    echo("This is a debugging message!")
    echo("This is a debugging message!", 0)
    echo("This is a debugging message!", 1)
    echo("This is a debugging message!", 2)
```

And the output:

```
Echo: This is a debugging message! Level: 1
Log: This is a debugging message! Level: 2
```